# Can't find a file by pattern

Tags: linux

ALL,

Following command `find . -name *h` throws following:

```
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

The command runs but throwing both .h and .cpp files.

What is the problem here?

TIA!!

Comment: Wrap `*h` in quotes, like so `"*h"` ... the problem is that the shell expands the `*h` ...

Comment: @tink, yes, it does. Thx. I'll upvote the answer.